# Only return inner element from nested array in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I currently have a collection that contains documents like this

```
{
    "_id" : "sHXFGyTkZBYeZXcax",
    "name" : "Sunless Sunday",
    "description" : "blabla",
    "game_id" : "qPrZBahQLHQXabwuv",
    "date_checkin" : ISODate("2015-11-07T01:01:00.000Z"),
    "date_start" : ISODate("2015-11-12T00:04:00.000Z"),
    "date_end" : ISODate("2015-11-19T00:05:00.000Z"),
    "company_id" : 1,
    "featured" : 1,
    "premium" : 0,
    "type" : 0,
    "ongoing" : 1,
    "prizes" : [ 
        {
            "place" : 1,
            "amount" : 18
        }, 
        {
            "place" : 2,
            "amount" : 2
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-05T22:34:01.494Z"),
    "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2015-11-05T22:34:01.494Z"),
    "owner" : "CLEopD9HRAeE9eiXW",
    "players" : [ 
        {
            "player_id" : "WdLK9aaRgdPnYsw8B",
            "status" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "vF6JEwMy9yaRtKuiG",
            "status" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : -1
        }, 
        {
            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
            "status" : 1
        }
    ],
    "rounds" : [ 
        {
            "roundNumber" : 1,
            "participants" : [],
            "matchesToWin" : 3,
            "matches" : [ 
                {
                    "matchNumber" : 1,
                    "party1" : "WdLK9aaRgdPnYsw8B"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "roundNumber" : 2,
            "participants" : [ 
                {
                    "player_id" : "WdLK9aaRgdPnYsw8B",
                    "status" : 2
                }, 
                {
                    "player_id" : "vF6JEwMy9yaRtKuiG",
                    "status" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
                    "status" : 1
                }
            ],
            "matchesToWin" : 2,
            "matches" : [ 
                {
                    "matchNumber" : 1,
                    "players" : [ 
                        {
                            "party" : 1
                        }, 
                        {
                            "player_id" : "WdLK9aaRgdPnYsw8B",
                            "party" : 2
                        }
                    ],
                    "party1" : "freewin",
                    "party2" : "WdLK9aaRgdPnYsw8B",
                    "currentGame" : 1,
                    "winner" : "WdLK9aaRgdPnYsw8B",
                    "matchFinished" : ISODate("2015-11-16T16:25:37.712Z")
                }, 
                {
                    "matchNumber" : 2,
                    "players" : [ 
                        {
                            "player_id" : "vF6JEwMy9yaRtKuiG",
                            "party" : 1
                        }, 
                        {
                            "player_id" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
                            "party" : 2
                        }
                    ],
                    "party1" : "vF6JEwMy9yaRtKuiG",
                    "party2" : "KD4s2E3AezhFcQDCd",
                    "score1" : 0,
                    "score2" : 0,
                    "currentGame" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to see if a certain player has an active match. So this means that the the player would be either party1 or party2 in a match that has no winner at the moment.

I currently have this query

```
activeMatch = Tournaments.find({
        'ongoing': 1,
        'rounds.matches': {
          $elemMatch: {
            $or: [
              { 'party1': player[0]._id },
              { 'party2': player[0]._id },
            ],
            winner: { $exists: false }
          }
        }
      },
      { "rounds.matches.$": 1 }
    );
```

I have 2 problems at the moment:

- My query returns the round it matched, but it does not filter for the match it matched. So I effectively only get round with roundNumber = 2, but from that round I get every match, where as I would only be interested in a specific match.
- The filtering only happens when I execute my query through the shell. When I use it in my .jsx file and console.log the result to the client, I see ALL rounds.

Any help?

Comment: If you want the server to do the filtering then you are going to need `.aggregate()` for this as basic projection cannot possibly manipulate beyond selection of the top level elements. The most performant methods may be difficult to understand. You are probably better off just filtering out the content in code and publishing the modified results as another collection if all this is really doing is filtering content from documents.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to spread my data out over multiple collections, thanks anyway!